# How does Sun influence the Andromeda Galaxy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Okay.. This was a rather crazy spin off in thought when I was reviewing Newton's law of universal gravitation.

$$ F = \frac{Gm_1 m_2}{r^2}. $$

The force only dies off at infinity i.e the force although ridiculously small still persists at large distances. What does this mean? Can the sun in theory influence the Andromeda galaxy?

Comment: Yes, the sun does influence Andromeda galaxy.

Comment: For that matter, every single atom in Andromeda (or as far away as you like) will have a gravitational effect on the sun, the earth and your body.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity has no range beyond which it ceases to have an effect. So yes, the Sun can influence the Andromeda galaxy. You can, as well. If you decide to live in Canada as opposed to India for example, Andromeda will react very (very) slightly to your body moving.